# Difference between those declarations

Tags: delphi, parameters, delphi-7

I am learning Delphi since the beginning of this week and I am currently reading the `Delphi 7 - Developer's Guide`. In this book (Chapter 5-37), the author declares a function as follow:

```
function FromEuro(const AValue: Double, Factor; FRound: TRoundToRange): Double;
```

If I had to write this function, I would have written it as follow:

```
function FromEuro(const AValue, Factor: Double; FRound: TRoundToRange): Double;
```

My question is : Is there any difference between those declarations ?

Comment: The first declaration won't compile. Probably a typo. There's no difference between them.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't really tried that line in a program and as you said it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you meant to ask is what is the difference between these two:

```
function FromEuro(const AValue: Double; Factor: Double): Double; 
function FromEuro(const AValue, Factor: Double): Double;
```

The second variant is a contraction that expands to:

```
function FromEuro(const AValue: Double; const Factor: Double): Double;
```

And this differs from

```
function FromEuro(const AValue: Double; Factor: Double): Double;
```

by way of the second parameter being `const`.

Note that I removed the final parameter since it is not relevant to the question.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)) says:

> A parameter list is a sequence of parameter declarations separated by semicolons and enclosed in parentheses. Each declaration is a comma-delimited series of parameter names, followed in most cases by a colon and a type identifier, and in some cases by the = symbol and a default value.

What the documentation doesn't mention is that each of the parameters in a comma-delimited series of parameter names has the same type. I guess this is meant to be obvious, and it does follow the example set by variable declarations. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables) for variables says:

> The basic syntax for a variable declaration is:
>
> ```
> var identifierList:type;
> ```
>
> where identifierList is a comma-delimited list of valid identifiers
>   and type is any valid type. For example:
>
> ```
> var I: Integer;
> ```
>
> declares a variable I of type Integer, while:
>
> ```
> var X, Y: Real;
> ```
>
> declares two variables - X and Y - of type Real.

On the other hand, perhaps you know all of this already, and all that we have is a typo in a book! And indeed that seems to be the case because the exact same typo can be found here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_a_Class_to_Manage_Conversions

Comment: Final parameter was in the book's example so I put it but you're right, it is not really relevant to the question. 
Anyway thanks for your explanations. I didn't really test the line the author gived but seems like it is a typo.

Comment: If that's how it is in the book, then it's a typo for sure.

Comment: I knew most of the things you said and was more confused by the typo (that I didn't know was a typo) but anyway, your answer is perfect. Thank you again. ;)

Comment: I assumed that the typo was in the transcription from the book to the question. So sorry if I lectured you on what you already knew!

Comment: As I said, I'm a beginner in Delphi and your answer is a good reminder. :)

Comment: The only difference is that `Factor` is now a `const` argument but that should not matter here

Comment: The typo is also in this link http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_a_Class_to_Manage_Conversions ... :/